# Prove that triangles AEF, BFD, CDE are similar to ABC

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

[image]

I am actually unable to solve this question.

It is asked to prove that

> In the figure, triangles AEF, BFD, and CDE are each similar to ABC.

I got to the point that angle $BAC =EHC$ (here $H$ is the orthocentre) using cyclic quadrilateral. Then I tried using the fact that the $H$ is the incentre of the pedal triangle but still couldn't advance much further.

Could anyone please help me with this question?

Also I am new to these triangles, so I might not understand higher concepts. Please try to explain with basic ones only.

Comment: Hint: $ABDE$ is cyclic so $\angle BED = \angle BAD = 90^\circ - \angle B$. So, $\angle CED = \angle B$. That makes $\triangle CED \sim \triangle ABC$. Check similarly for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\small \angle ADB=\angle AEB=90^\circ\implies ABDE\text{ is cyclic}.$

Therefore $\small \angle ADE=\angle ABE=90^\circ-\angle A.$

Since $\small \angle ADC=90^\circ$, from the above we can see $\small \angle EDC=\angle A.$

Now, $\small \angle EDC=\angle A$ and $\small \angle ECD=\angle C$. Thus $\small \triangle DEC\sim\triangle ABC.$

Likewise, we can prove other given triangles are similiar as well. Can you do that?